# Subtract 2 array values having floating point decimals

Tags: bash, unix

I'm reading a file with multiple columns, and dumping 2 columns of the file into  into 2 different arrays. Now based on a condition, I need to get the difference between 2 values retrieved from the array. So my code looks like this -

```
if [ condition ]; then
VAL = (( ${local[$x]} - ${local[$y]} ))
fi
```

The thing is, while I'm able to echo and see both values `${local[$x]}` and `${local[$y]}`, the subtraction operation gives me a syntax error. I understand it's failing because the values currently held within the array involve floating point decimal values - like 3456712.126758, and the assignment throws errors with the decimal part. I understand arithmetic operations are not a strong point with the bash shell as floating point numbers are considered strings hence the issue.

Could you please help getting the right format please?
Should I do something like this

```
VAL= awk '{ print ${local[$x]} - ${local[$y]} }'
```

or

```
VAL=echo ${local[$x]} - ${local[$y]} | bc -l
```

I'm sure the syntax above is wrong, kindly help with the syntax, I need it assigned the subtracted result assigned to the field `VAL`.

Comment: This is a very basic bash question. You would benefit from working though a bash tutorial. There are a couple of links on the [bash tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info), see the Resources section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only floating points, but also the spacing would lead to syntax errors. Bash variable assignments must have no spaces, as in `val=x`, and not `val = x`.

Uppercase variable names are reserved for environment variables, and it is recommended to use lowercase instead for your own variables. (Oh, and `local` is *also* a reserved word.)

Your assignment wouldn't work with proper spacing, either: the [arithmetic expression](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs)

```
var=(( ${vals[$x]} - ${vals[$y]} ))   # syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

is just evaluating its contents, but not returning anything. You could use the part after the `=` as a condition. To make it return something, you need [arithmetic expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) (note the extra `$`):

```
var=$(( ${vals[$x]} - ${vals[$y]} ))    # works for integers
    ^
```

In an arithmetic context, you don't even need to prepend `$` to your variables:

```
var=$(( vals[x] - vals[y] ))
```

works just as well. Exception: in [associative arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays), you still have to do it for indices:

```
$(( vals[$x] ))
```

And finally, as you noticed, this all doesn't work for floating point numbers. Instead of piping to `bc`, you can also use a [here string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings) and avoid spawning a subshell:

```
$ vals=(1.1 2.2)
$ x=0
$ y=1
$ echo $(( local[x] - local[y] ))    # No '$' needed for variable expansion
bash: 1.1: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".1")  # But :(
$ bc -l <<< "local[x] - local[y]"   # Requires '$' - these expand to nothing
0
$ bc -l <<< "${local[x]} - ${local[y]}"   # Works!
-1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
awk -v a=${a} -v b=${b} 'BEGIN{print a - b}'
```

With bc:

```
echo "${a} - ${b}" | bc -l
```

See also other options [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40787/65213).

Comment: and to capture the result: `val=$(echo ... | bc -l)`